# How can I fix messy hair in Animal Crossing?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I time-warped in *Animal Crossing: New Leaf* so I could get to the award ceremonies for the Bug-Off. I time-warped a year ahead, and now my hair's all messy. How can I put my hair back to normal?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, you will need to have a Shampoodle's on Main Street. You can get Shampoodle's by spending 10,000 Bell at the Able Sisters after unlocking Kicks. You can do this after spending at least 8,000 Bells in the Able Sisters after you have played the game for at least 10 days. Then, when Shampoodle's is open for business, she will ask you a couple of questions on how you want your hair to look. The process will cost 3,000 Bell, but will be worth it after you see the kind of hair you got!

Comment: Can I visit the Shampoodle in a friend's town?

Answer (score 10):

You can fix messy hair by going to Shampoodles. Shampoodles can be found on main street.